# Update values from URL parameters

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic

The requirement is for a certain value in an embedded script to be dynamically updated via URL parameter; in the below, the (desired) variable is ***nasdaq:aapl***

The end goal would be that a new url paramater (e.g. Site.com/?symbol=***nasdaq:googl***) would update/re-populate the dynamic value in the code.

```
new Tr.widget({
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "nasdaq:aapl",                        
  "studies": [""]
});
```

Comment: Just google: ”js get url parameters” - and you get plenty of examples how to get the values

Comment: See Example #1 at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location for an exmple on how to navigate a new page.  You can do this in an iframe if you want your page to show the new page within it.  As to the parameters,  see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp which you can add to the string that you assign to location.